# Why does consulting a json file take so long on the real device and on the emulator is immediate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I execute a query to a json file through the fetch function and in the emulator the result is immediate, it takes a century on the real device (motorola one vision) to give results.

What can it be? I isolated the code in a project from scratch to see and the problem really is in the type of query.

Could it be some gradlew configuration when generating the APK?

Thank you in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

export default () => {      
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

    fetch('https://senhor.app/trilhas/restaurantes.json').then(data => setStatus(true));

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Funcional</Text>

            {
                status
                ?   <Text>Carregou</Text>
                : <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
            }
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Has your PC emulator the same internet connection of your device?

Comment: [[ Dev machine ]] -- local - instant [[ server ]]  vs [[ Device ]] -- remote - **unknown** [[ server ]] -- you've not provided enough information about the infrastructure to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, the connection is same of PC and smartphone.